# How do I get WebStorm using ts-node with node --inspect to hit the proper line?

Tags: typescript, webstorm, ts-node

I'm using TypeScript to power an Express application.

I have nodemon instantiating node with the `--inspect` option.

- I CAN connect a debug session, and hit a breakpoint in WebStorm.
- I cannot get it to hit the proper line.

Here's my **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es2017"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noResolve": false,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "test/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

[image]

**package.json**

```
"ts-node": "^5.0.1",
"typescript": "^2.7.2"
```

Why won't WebStorm hit the proper breakpoint and inspect the req / res?

Comment: such problems usually indicate sourcemap issues - if sourcemaps are not accurate enough, the line in source code can't be mapped to the one in executed file. Does the problem \persist when debugging in Dev tools?

Comment: @lena - what do you mean by Dev Tools?

Comment: Chrome Developer Tools - https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#chrome-devtools-55

Comment: @lena The break points work as expected in the chome dev tools

Comment: can you share a sample project I can use to recreate the issue?

Comment: I'm afraid i cant - we pay for quite a few licenses - id be happy to talk to tech support